# Convert cartesian to cylindrical for an equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Convert $z^2 = x^2 - y^2$ to cylindrical.

We know by definition,

$x = r\cos(\theta), y = r\sin(\theta)$

Therefore

$$z^2 = r^2(\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta))$$

Is that the final form or can it be simplified?

Comment: Do you know the double-angle formulas for cosine?

Comment: So would it be 

$$z^2 = r^2(\cos(2\theta))$$


I'm mainly confused about the $$z^2$$, seems odd.

Comment: Yes, $\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)$. You can take square roots of both sides, but take care with positive and negative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing things from the comments, with a few more details, so that you can accept an answer and close out this question...

You get $$
z^2 = r^2 \cos (2 \theta).
$$
The notion of "final form" isn't really well-defined, but you HAVE expressed the equation, at this point, in terms of $(z, r, \theta)$, which is all that's required.

Notice that in polar coordinates, $r$ must be nonnegative (although sometimes we allow negative $r$ values in equations like $r = \cos \theta$).

From the form shown, you can see that if $(z, r, \theta) = (z_0, r_0, \theta_0)$ is a solution, then $(z, r, \theta) = (-z_0, r_0, \theta_0)$ is also a solution. If you casually take the square root of both sides, getting 
$$
z = r \sqrt{\cos (2 \theta)},
$$
you miss the negative-$z$ solutions; the right version is 
$$
|z| = |r| \sqrt{\cos (2 \theta)},
$$
which (if you're restricting to positive $r$ values) becomes
$$
|z| = r \sqrt{\cos (2 \theta)},
$$
which entails two $z$-values for every $r, \theta$ pair (except when $r = 0$).

Notice, too, that the square root makes sense only when $\cos(2\theta) \ge 0$, which is to say 
$$
-\frac{\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}
$$ or 
$$
-\frac{3\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{5\pi}{4}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite as

$$z=\pm r\sqrt{\cos2\theta}$$ which is defined only for $\cos2\theta\ge0$.

Whether this is the final form or not is a matter of taste.